# Warning message: In log(t.dat) : NaNs produced even with na.omit=T

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, nan, logarithm

I want to create a new data frame by appending the `label` binary vector to a large dataframe `t.dat`. `NaNs` are produced even when I use `na.omit=T`, which means the `NaNs`were not due to 0 values.

```
label <- as.factor(c(rep(0, 21-1+1),rep(1,177-22+1))) # Binary vector 0=non-tumor and 1=glioma
svm.df <-data.frame(label, log(t.dat), na.omit=T)
```

> Warning message: In log(t.dat) : NaNs produced

```
> which(is.nan(log(t.dat)))
 [1]  597849  656262  673097  869853  949681  949692  949700  949725  949728
[10] 1255020 1255029 1427194 1462292 1462370 1946921 2085039 2375207 2375324
[19] 2459488 2471475 2756957 2756962 2756964 2756973 2756982 2757015 2757103
[28] 2757113 2757114 2757117 2757123 2866715 2966242 2966248 3108773 3612388
[37] 3712228 4106033 4863666 4863703 5011987 5012045 5012068 5266896 5358428
[46] 5361451 5494337 5630823 5733845 5733910 5815590 5815592 5815621 5815632
[55] 5815635 5941255 5941305 6073404 6073416 6073456 6073493 6073510 6073521
[64] 6073559 6100700 6100735 6100757 6100786 6239608 6239635 6239646 6239664
[73] 6239719 6425198 6476611 6489147 6865672 6905857 6966059 7049793 7148523
[82] 7172428 7172547 7623457 7726116 7829439 7829468 7829499 8008035
```

Comment: Please show us the contents of the rows of `t.dat` that are listed in the output from `which(is.nan(log(t.dat)))`.

Answer (score 1):

(1) `data.frame` doesn't have an `na.omit` argument (check the documentation), so the effect of including `na.omit=T` will be to include an entire column called `na.omit` to your data frame.
(2) NaN values arise (in this case) from taking the log of a negative number. If you want to filter these out, you could try

```r
ok <- which(t.dat >= 0)
svm.df <-data.frame(label[ok], log(t.dat[ok]))
```